# Formatted table output, printing into R console

Tags: r, dataframe, format

I have function that processes some data and I would like to print the intermediate steps while the function (a loop) proceeds. I could do that in 1 point where the updated data is all in one `data.frame()`. I'm thinking of some simple table as for example I saw as part of Rapporter tool box.

So the question is how or whether it is possible to print table with numerical values into console.

Thanks.

EDIT: `print()` is not the solution I'm after and here is why:

function `print()` prints the numeric values into console, but its a messy bunch of numbers. I would like to have kind of table to easily check the values while the function proceeds. So I can better orientate in the numeric values.

Comment: Have you tried ``print``?

Comment: how is it messy and how do you want it to look? I normally use print and I am fine with the outcome.

Comment: Its about 8 columns and 5 rows of kind of approx. equal numbers, I could insert a kind of `pause` into the loop, but I'm looking for simple table that would at least divide the columns with `==` or any other sign.

Comment: its data.frame() but I'm happy if you provide solution also with matrix or any other format you wish.

Comment: How about apply `round(df$num_vec, 2)`, so that floating numbers don't make clutter. And then proceed with `print`?

Comment: Please add your data.frame, otherwise it is hard to help you.

Comment: @all. Can you answer this simple question? Is it possible to print any kind of looking  table into R console?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this?

```
require(knitr)

for(i in 1:2){
  #some calculation 
  x<-runif(runif(1,1,5))
  y<-length(x)

  #dataframe output
  df <- cbind(x,y)

  #pretty table
  print(kable(df))
}


#output
#   |         x|  y|
#   |---------:|--:|
#   | 0.4872941|  3|
#   | 0.8014921|  3|
#   | 0.7023384|  3|
#   
#   
#   |         x|  y|
#   |---------:|--:|
#   | 0.9214315|  4|
#   | 0.7119830|  4|
#   | 0.0354769|  4|
#   | 0.1049139|  4|
```