# Transpose table columns shift

Tags: r, transpose

I have a table like this (note the empty cell in the top-left):

```
          C1 C2 C3 C4
R1         0  0  0  0
R2         1  0  1  1
```

And when I transpose using

```
table<-read.table(file="test_table.txt", header = TRUE)
table_t<-t(table)
write.table(table_t, file="transposed_test.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE)
```

I get the following:

```
R1 R2
C1 0 1
C2 0 0
C3 0 1
C4 0 1
```

See how the new columns (R1 and R2) have shifted to the left? How can I stop this happening?

Comment: R1 and R2 are the labels of the two data columns. C1:C4 are the labels of the data rows. So there are only two labels for the columns because there are only two columns. What are you trying to do with the output file?
If you want a formatted table do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28896229/1172358

Comment: Sure but I need the column headers positioned above the data columns. The headers are getting shifted to the left post-transpose such that the once empty cell (top-left) now has a header and the final column is without one.

Comment: Are the “R” and “C” labels here row or column names or are they contained in normal cells? That is: does table[0,1] = C1 or 0?

Comment: Hi Divibsian. The R and C labels were stored in cells (in the Excel sheet I used to generate the file) and were specified as row/column identifiers with table<-read.table(file="small_test_table.txt", header = TRUE, row.names = 1) when reading into R. table[0,1] returns integer(0). Are my headers not being recognized as headers? Odd since colnames[table] and row.names[table] returns "C1" "C2" "C3" "C4" and "R1" "R2", respectively.

Comment: PS No such problems if I perform the same actions with read.csv and a .csv file.